# Rails::TestUnitReporter can't find the methods of MiniTest::Result tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

Running `rails test`, `Rails::TestUnitReporter` is having trouble picking up the source location of `MiniTest::Result` tests.  The structure of `MiniTest::Result` isn't what `Rails::TestUnitReporter` expects.

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:71`:in `method': undefined method `test_It_calcualtes_late_fees_correctly' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
```

Inserting a byebug call, I see:

```
[66, 75] in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb
   66:         "%s#%s = %.2f s = %s" % [result.class, result.name, result.time, result.result_code]
   67:       end
   68: 
   69:       def format_rerun_snippet(result)
   70:         byebug if not Rails.env.production?
=> 71:         location, line = result.method(result.name).source_location
   72:         "#{self.executable} #{relative_path_for(location)}:#{line}"
   73:       end
   74: 
   75:       def app_root

(byebug) results.first.source_location
["/home/xxx/code/prj/test/models/invoice_template_test.rb", 9]
```

My test:

```
 4 class InvoiceTemplateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  5     test "the truth" do
  6       assert true
  7     end
  8 
  9     test "It calcualtes late fees correctly" do
 10         tests = {
 11             fixed_fee: {
 12                 feePolicy: '10.0 $ > 50',
 13                 pastDue: 52.0,
 [...]
 25             },
 26             decimal_fee: {
 27                 feePolicy: '0.1',
 28                 pastDue: 24.4,
 29                 expectedFee: 2.44,
 30             },
 31         }
 32 
  33         tests.each {|scenario, parameters|
 34             policy = parameters[:feePolicy]
 35             it = InvoiceTemplate.new(late_fee: policy)
 36 
 37             expected = parameters[:expectedFee]
 38             actual = it.calculateLateFee(parameters[:pastDue])
 39             msg = "For scenario #{scenario.to_s}, expected #{expected} and got #{actual}"
 40             assert_in_delta(expected, actual, 0.001, msg)
 41         }
 42 
 43     end
 44 end
```

If I comment out `"It calcualtes late fees correctly"`, it runs `"the truth"` correctly:

```
$ rvm 2.3.1 do rails test 
Running via Spring preloader in process 10308
Run options: --seed 37453

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.003080s, 324.6650 runs/s, 324.6650 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
$
```

It's not having trouble running the tests, it's having trouble reporting back cleanly from them.   Inserting a test with `assert false`, I get same error:

```
  9     test "the false" do
 10       assert false
 11     end
$ rvm 2.3.1 do rails test                                                                                                                                                      
Running via Spring preloader in process 16606
Run options: --seed 30320

# Running:

F

Failure:
InvoiceTemplateTest#test_the_false [/home/xxx/code/prj/test/models/invoice_template_test.rb:10]:
Expected false to be truthy.



[66, 75] in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb
   66:         "%s#%s = %.2f s = %s" % [result.class, result.name, result.time, result.result_code]
   67:       end
   68: 
   69:       def format_rerun_snippet(result)
   70:         byebug if not Rails.env.production?
=> 71:         location, line = result.method(result.name).source_location
   72:         "#{self.executable} #{relative_path_for(location)}:#{line}"
   73:       end
   74: 
   75:       def app_root
(byebug) c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:71:in `method': undefined method `test_the_false' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
```

I don't think it's the double gems directory, it runs inside the same installation for the whole stack trace:

```
lusk 10:24:39 {t15209_railsUnitTest} ~/code/prj/test$ rvm 2.3.1 do rails test                                                                                                                                                 
Running via Spring preloader in process 11485
Run options: --seed 58861

# Running:

F

Failure:
InvoiceTemplateTest#test_It_calcualtes_late_fees_correctly [/home/xxx/code/prj/test/models/invoice_template_test.rb:40]:
For scenario minimum, expected 0.0 and got 10.0.
Expected |0.0 - 10.0| (10.0) to be <= 0.001.



[66, 75] in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb
   66:         "%s#%s = %.2f s = %s" % [result.class, result.name, result.time, result.result_code]
   67:       end
   68: 
   69:       def format_rerun_snippet(result)
   70:         byebug if not Rails.env.production?
=> 71:         location, line = result.method(result.name).source_location
   72:         "#{self.executable} #{relative_path_for(location)}:#{line}"
   73:       end
   74: 
   75:       def app_root
(byebug) c
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:71:in `method': undefined method `test_It_calcualtes_late_fees_correctly' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:71:in `format_rerun_snippet'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:23:in `record'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:803:in `block in record'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:802:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:802:in `record'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:334:in `run_one_method'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:321:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `block in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:360:in `on_signal'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:347:in `with_info_handler'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:319:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:9:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `block in __run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `map'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `__run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:136:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

If I include `rails_helper`, I get more conflict, seemingly internal to rails:

```
$ rvmDo rails test                                     
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails_helper-2.2.2/lib/rails_helper.rb:138:in `block in <class:Engine>': undefined method `install_helpers' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x000000055c1b10>
Did you mean?  instance_values (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `block in execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:65:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
```

I suppose the double stacked gem installation could be at the fault of incompatibiilty between `MiniTest::Result` and `Rails::TestUnitReporter`.  But before I re-install my entire rvm, rails and ruby installation, is there any gem I should try to upgrade with `bundle update --conservative gem-name` ?

*Update*: Futher looking into what version and which gem of the two I'm running:

```
(byebug) list=

[66, 75] in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb
   66:         "%s#%s = %.2f s = %s" % [result.class, result.name, result.time, result.result_code]
   67:       end
   68: 
   69:       def format_rerun_snippet(result)
   70:         byebug if not Rails.env.production?
=> 71:         location, line = result.method(result.name).source_location
   72:         "#{self.executable} #{relative_path_for(location)}:#{line}"
   73:       end
   74: 
   75:       def app_root

(byebug) Minitest::Result.singleton_methods.map{|m| Minitest::Result.method(m).source_location[0]}.uniq

["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb", "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/core_ext.rb"]
```

So they are both from inside `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/` .     I'm going to see if there are knonwn incompatibiilties between `railties-5.0.7` and `minitest-5.11.3` and determine which one I should upgrade.

Comment: A college has suggested to pin minitest to 5.10.3 (or I guess upgrade to rails 5.1) given https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31624 .  I have not tested this yet.